# Plotly: searching for element in scatter3d graph object

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, scatter3d

I am trying to visualize some text data in a cluster using the example [here](https://www.kaggle.com/code/huseinzol05/visualize-word-vector)

I managed to run the code successfully and now I have the interactive plot shown in the end which looks like this.

[image]

I would like to search for a word in all the data points. Notice how if you hover over each point the text of the word shows up but I don't know how to look for a specific word since there are thousands of data points. Any ideas?

Comment: You want to search for a word and the figure tells where it is or how?

Comment: @Hamzah yes exactly, to locate a word on the figure